# Skip 5 latest post while paging?

Tags: loop, pagination, homepage

In the `index.php` page, I need to skip 5 posts (the last 5 posts in the blog).

I use [the WP-Paginate plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/), but all pages show the same. I'm using `offset=5`, this is my code:

```
<?php  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;?>
<?php   $additional_loop = new WP_Query("offset=5&paged=".$paged);  
        if ($additional_loop->have_posts()) :

        while ($additional_loop->have_posts()) : $additional_loop->the_post();
        the_title();?><br/>
        <?php the_content();?>
        <?php endwhile;endif;?>
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
    wp_paginate('range=4&anchor=2&nextpage=Next&previouspage=Previous');
} ?>
```

Comment: Give this one a try: https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Easy-Pagination-Deamon It can be used as plugin, but is meant to show you how pagination can be done in wp.

Comment: You cannot use an offset with the paged parameter, the paging system sets the offset, when you set an offset you mess up the paging. If you use an offset you must create your own paging system(ie. build paging links yourself).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify either `paged` for simple pagination, or `offset` [if you want to do something special](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-show-a-single-post-on-the-front-page-but-have-normal-paging). Calculating the offset yourself is easy: just multiply the current page number (minus two) with the number of posts per page, and add your start offset:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
$additional_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'offset' => ( $paged - 2 ) * $posts_per_page + 5,
) );
```

I see you use `wp_paginate()`, but this function does not know you are using an additional query and [will read the global `$wp_query` object](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-paginate/tags/1.2.3/wp-paginate.php#L112) to get the current page and total number of pages, unless you pass these values yourself:

```
wp_paginate( array(
    'range' => 4,
    'anchor' => 2,
    'nextpage' => 'Next',
    'previouspage' => 'Previous',
    'page' => $paged,
    'pages' => intval( ceil( $additional_loop->found_posts / $posts_per_page ) ),
) );
```

This is an additional loop, so there still is a "normal" loop on this page? Watch out that this will not confuse pagination, because WordPress will also try to paginate that loop and return a 404 if it is exhausted - which may be before you reach the last page. Try to do pagination only in the main loop, with the `pre_get_posts` hook.