# Number of posts in the archive

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, pagination, query, get-posts

How do I show 10 posts on the first page of the archive, and 20 on others (>1)?

My custom post type name is "apartments".

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `posts_per_page` variable depending on the page you are on, so make it 10 on the first page and 20 on the other pages. However, you will have to [modify the `offset` query variable too](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-show-a-single-post-on-the-front-page-but-have-normal-paging/237#237), otherwise you will skip posts 11-20 on the second page, because this page thinks they are already displayed on the first page.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse15087_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse15087_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
{
    if ( $wp_query->is_post_type_archive( 'apartments' ) ) {
        if ( ! $wp_query->is_paged() ) {
            $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        } else {
            $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
            $wp_query->set( 'offset', ( ( $wp_query->get( 'paged' ) - 2 ) * 20 ) + 10 );
        }
    }
}
```