# Set a custom number of posts on the first page

Tags: pre-get-posts

I need to limit the posts shown in WordPress front page on the first page only.
The reason for it is a sticky post which breaks my layout and the number of total post set up in default WP setting.

I found this function for `functions.php` but it appears to not work.

Can you help me to fix it? I prefer a `functions.php` change.

I wonder if it's not working because post with this snippet is really new.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sk_change_posts_per_page' );

/**
 * Change Posts Per Page for first page of Posts page
 *
 * @param object $query data
 */
function sk_change_posts_per_page( $query ) {

  if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
  }

}
```

[Source](http://sridharkatakam.com/set-custom-number-posts-first-page-posts-page-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

The `pre_get_posts` runs before `WP_Query` has been setup. Some template tags and conditional functions that rely on `WP_Query` will not work. you will need to work directly with the query vars, which are passed to the `pre_get_posts` hook as an argument.

See the more information on the following pages: [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and [using `pre_get_posts`](http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/when-to-use-pre_get_posts-in-wordpress)

Try using the following code.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sk_change_posts_per_page' );

/**
 * Change Posts Per Page for first page of Posts page
 *
 * @param object $query data
 */
function sk_change_posts_per_page( $query ) {

  if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_home() && ! $query->is_paged() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
  }

}
```

Comment: just tested your code in functions.php . no effect. thx for the try.

Comment: @Nicy Which theme are you using?

Have you developed custom page template to display posts on the front page?

Comment: Its a thumbnail image gallery not real posts. Ive tested an other code it works but on all pages not only at the first. i can find it again

Comment: also maybe an other snippet could be incompatible with your code`? for example: function filter_posts() {
global $wp_query;
if(is_home()) {
$wp_query->set('category__not_in',array(41558,42051,42054)); // ID der Kategorie to exclude
}
}

Comment: ive also tested this code not work: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-show-a-single-post-on-the-front-page-but-have-normal-paging